# How to display paragraph as column with abbr inside?

Tags: css

I practice css on zengarden.

[I want something like this, but with no h3 column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGAwC.png)

HTML

```
<div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
        <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
        <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible 
            <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> 
        support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
        <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the 
            <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>, 
            <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr>
        , and the major browser creators.</p>
        <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
</div>
```

I also try.

```
.preamble :not(h3){
    display: flex;
}
```

[I got this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft788.png)

Maybe It's because of abbr inside p tag.
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Where h3 should be?

Comment: @Greg-- I want it to be in the middle of the top like the 2nd picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) could fit here. If the heading should span the whole width, you can set the `column-span` property.

You may also need to style the paragraph to your liking (e.g. adjust margin).

See [MDN Multiple-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Multiple-column_Layout) for more information.

```css
.preamble {
  columns: 3;
}

h3 {
  column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
  <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
  <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible
    <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
  <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the
    <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>,
    <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr> , and the major browser creators.</p>
  <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need remove h3 from that div for centered it

```css
.preamble {
  display: flex;
}

h3{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
<div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
  <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible
    <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
  <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the
    <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>,
    <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr> , and the major browser creators.</p>
  <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
</div>
```